# Unreachable statement when trying to call getItemCount() twice

Tags: java, android

I am trying to call `getItemCount()` twice but get an unreachable statement. Any idea how to return two counts without getting the following problem?

[image]

Comment: A method can have only one possible result or outcome for any given execution.

Comment: My original answer actually couldn’t work because I realized that you are overriding another method, so you can’t change the return type. Is it necessary to override the method you have shown?

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one `return` statement per method. You either need to have two separate methods to return the separate values or put those values in a data structure and return the data structure

So you could do something like:

```
public int getDataSourceCount() {
   return mDataSource.size();
}
public int getImageCount() {
   return mImageURL.size();
}
```

Comment: I upvoted but in the OP’s post, he is overriding a method, so I don’t know if he wants two seperate methods to return the values.

Answer (score 1):

That `getItemCount()` method is the adapter's way of figuring out how many items (rows) to show the user. It is an absolute requirement that you return only one `int` value from this method, and that this value be the number of items you want the user to be able to see.

Given that your original question shows that you're using two lists, it seems likely that you should do one of two things:

**1 - Return the sum of the two sizes**

Perhaps you're trying to say that your recyclerview should show all of your datasource items and then all of your image items. In this case, you'd want to write

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSource.size() + mImageUrls.size();
}
```

**2 - Return the size of mDataSource**

It's often the case that you have multiple lists *of the same size*, each of which holds only a part of the data you want to show the user inside each row. Perhaps `mDataSource` is a list of 20 albums, including artist, song name, etc. And perhaps `mImageUrls` is a list of 20 strings, with each being the art for an album cover.

In this case, you can just return the size of any of these lists (since they're all equal):

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDataSource.size();
}
```

Then, in your `onBindViewHolder()` method, you can pull the data you need out of each list:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Object albumInfo = mDataSource.get(position);
    String albumCoverUrl = mImageUrls.get(position);
    ...
}
```